# Error when Building an Android Project that references Facebook

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, build

I'm running a build target in my Android project, and it fails with this in the console log:

```
-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] Gathering info for MyGameProject...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 19
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.2
    [setup] API level: 8
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] E:\Android\workspace\MyGameProject: ../../facebook-android-sdk/facebook => E:\Android\facebook-android-sdk\facebook
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Ordered libraries:
    [setup] E:\Android\facebook-android-sdk\facebook
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
    [setup] ------------------
-build-setup:
     [echo] Building Libraries

BUILD FAILED
E:\Android\workspace\MyGameProject\build.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:515: The following error occurred while executing this line:
Target "${build.target}" does not exist in the project "facebook".
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the Manifest code? And what library are you using for Facebook integration?

Comment: have you also updated the facebook library project ?

Answer (score 1):

facebook-android-sdk default not have build.xml

You can create; go to facebook-sdk dir and execute command line:

```
android update project -p .
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried executing the command. I do have a build.xml in the facebook folder. But running the build target in ant still shows that error. It's not an error that stops my game from building the rest of it. My game still runs even with this error.